# Image is not removed from AbsoluteLayout's Children on Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, task, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms PCL project.

I made my timer and call this function every three seconds.

```
    void CreateBGAndAnimate()
    {
        Image bg = new Image()
        {
            Source = "_pagebaby_bg.png",
            Aspect = Aspect.Fill
        };
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(bg, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bg, new Rectangle(0.5, 1, 1, 0.5));

        xAbsoluteLayout.Children.Insert(1, bg);
        bg.Opacity = 0;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await bg.FadeTo(1, 500);
            await bg.ScaleTo(2, 1000, Easing.SinInOut);
            xAbsoluteLayout.Children.Remove(bg);
        });
    }
```

And very weird problem. 
FIrst Image never be removed.
And Image created after first one are removed as I expected.

Is there someone facing same issue?

What did i wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Run UI operations in MainThread.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you see here, but consider using `Task.Run()` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew()`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/ and http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have do your UI operation in the UI thread (Main Thread). 
For that use the [Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/) method.

```
void CreateBGAndAnimate()
{
    Image bg = new Image()
    {
        Source = "_pagebaby_bg.png",
        Aspect = Aspect.Fill
    };
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(bg, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bg, new Rectangle(0.5, 1, 1, 0.5));

    xAbsoluteLayout.Children.Insert(1, bg);
    bg.Opacity = 0;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await bg.FadeTo(1, 500);
        await bg.ScaleTo(2, 1000, Easing.SinInOut);

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => xAbsoluteLayout.Children.Remove(bg));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's right. I thought that I don't have to use UI thread for removing view.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I would definitely make sure that the operations are running on the UI Thread and I switched around the `Opacity` and adding the control since you do not want the control to be visible for a split second after adding it in.

I also inserted a pause:

```
...

bg.Opacity = 0;
xAbsoluteLayout.Children.Insert(1, bg);

Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    await bg.FadeTo(1, 500);
    await bg.ScaleTo(2, 1000, Easing.SinInOut);
    xAbsoluteLayout.Children.Remove(bg);
});
```